# как сделать текст по середине?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

на *flexbox* я могу сделать `justify-content: space-between` 
но тут он не работает а `text-align: center;` не могу использовать по дизайну, а если делать отступы то нужно их будет долго рассчитывать на каждом разрешении

```css
* {
 border: 2px solid #e7e7e7

}



.inner {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Column -->
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 no-gutters">
      <div class="inner d-flex justify-content-center no-gutters m-auto">
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 no-gutters">
      <div class="inner d-flex justify-content-center no-gutters m-auto">
        <h1>voluptatibus</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur corporis dolorem eligendi enim mollitia quidem quis rem saepe sed voluptatibus?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 no-gutters">
      <div class="inner d-flex justify-content-center no-gutters m-auto">
        <h1>dolor</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 no-gutters">
      <div class="inner d-flex justify-content-center no-gutters m-auto">
        <h1>consectetur</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас эти блоки  вообще лишние. Нужные свойства поместил в класс item, хотя можно было и классами добавить. Когда уберете, если вам это нужно, стандартные отступы - все будет отцентрировано строго по вертикали

```css
* {
 border: 2px solid #e7e7e7
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Column -->
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 no-gutters item">
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 no-gutters item">
            <h1>voluptatibus</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elfditLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elfditLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elfdit. Aspernatur corporis dolorem eligendi enim
                mollitia quidem quis rem saepe sed voluptatibus?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 no-gutters item">

            <h1>dolor</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 no-gutters item">
            <h1>consectetur</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ но я больше имел  в виду как выровнять по горизонтали, не используя текст-цент

Comment: Нужно добавить align-items: center; Добавил в пример

Comment: Добавьте графический пример как это должно выглядеть. С радостью помогу